# Launch app in non-retina mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

I have made an app that works both on iPhone 4 and iPhone 3, but I don't have an iPhone 3 to test on.

Is there any way to start my app in iPhone 3 mode (e.g. Info.plist setting)?

Comment: Why does the simulator in non-retina mode not satisfy your needs?

Comment: I use the AVFoundation framework for camera and it doesn't work with the simulator afaik :-(

Comment: I could build the project without camera support just for testing purposes.. that would allow to run the siumulator, but still not on the real thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just a particular view (and not an image file) that you want to test on development code, draw to a view scaled down to a half-sized (in points) view on an iPhone 4, and then display and (re)scale that half-sized view by 2X to fill the display, with antialiasing turned off (kCGInterpolationNone).

There appears to be no automatic flag to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Not on an iPhone 4.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove all "@2x" retina files and you should see the old graphics. Another way would be the iPhone Simulator which runs by default in the old 320x480 pixel mode.

Comment: False. Retina is about more than just high res images. Text, drawn shapes etc. will remain high-res.

Comment: @Kenneth: I guess thats why I also mentioned the iPhone Simulator wise guy ;)